# passing an array from a jframe class in java

Tags: java, swing

I searched for this question on StackOverflow and found stuff that helped, but didn't understand clearly what can I do...

I have a jframe class which contains these codes (it's a part of my class)

```java
public class compiler extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form compiler
 */
public compiler() {
    initComponents();
}

/**

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {


    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


 String[] input= new String[500];
 input = jTextArea1.getText().split(" |\n" );
 int x=0;    
 int n=input.length;
 int k=0;
 String[] other = new String[100];
```

In this project, I have another class to which I want to pass "String other".  However, I don't know how to do it.

I think the problem is that `jButton1ActionPerformed` is a private method and I can't change it.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: for better help sooner, please include an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org). until then, voting to close.

Comment: post your complete test code

Comment: Can you give an example of the class you would like to pass your String[] other too?

Comment: @Bedwyr Humphreys please can you stop with ....

Answer (score 0):

One simple fix is declaring an instance of the class that you would like to pass the string[] to globally, (unless you will not need to keep it around). In the class that you would like to set the value on just define a method to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you want to do, something as simple as:

```
OtherClass.doSomethingWithStringOther(other);
```

added to the end of your event handler would work.  As mentioned above, that requires either a global variable representing the other class or a static method within the other class.

The alternative is making other global within your JFrame then writing a getter for it:

```
public String[] getOther(){
return other;
}
```

then having a call to getOther() in the other class.